# Eclipse IDE can't Commit & Push to GitHub

Tags: java, eclipse, github, push, commit

I tried to commit & push a file into my GitHub branch but I can't see the file on my branch. There's a pop up about it being rejected [Popup after Commit & Push](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1JIks.png). I also tried to pull from my repository/branch but I cannot too. [Error after trying to pull from my branch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m2wer.png). What should I do?

I tried to commit & push a file into my GitHub branch but I can't see the file on my branch. There's a pop up about it being rejected [Popup after Commit & Push](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1JIks.png). I also tried to pull from my repository/branch but I cannot too. [Error after trying to pull from my branch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m2wer.png).

Comment: please mention the git commands/ steps  you are using to commit and push.

Comment: Possible helpful: https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/using-git/dealing-with-non-fast-forward-errors and https://eclipsesource.com/blogs/tutorials/eclipse-git-tutorial-a-rebase-workflow-with-egit/

Comment: @codemaster, I add the file (.docs) to the index [Staged Changes] and then make a comment in the Commit Message. Commit & Push then a pop up for the GitHub login credentials. After that, a pop-up stating [Branch Name] - [Branch Name] [rejected -non -fast forward]

Comment: `rejected - non-fast-forward` means that your push was rejected by GitHub because changes have been made in the meantime. Maybe someone else have pushed commits to this GitHub repository, maybe you added or edit the `README.md` or other files via the web browser, maybe you applied pull requests or maybe you pushed commits from a different branch. Whatever, you can either do a force push to override the remote changes or merge or rebase the remote changes before pushing your changes. It's your decision and you can do it with Eclipse.